# MS Access: move deleted records automatically to "recycle bin" table

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-delete

I need to implement a copy of records right after they are deleted from the table, so they can be recovered in case of accidental deletion.

I am using MS Access. Is there any built in way to do it or will I have to INSERT INTO SELECT before every DELETE?

Doing it for just one table is not a concern. I want to use something ready for any table regardless of its structure, so I don't need to create and configure another recycle-bin-table for every table I have in the database, which would be necessary if I want successful move operations.

Besides SQL, I can run VBA to accomplish this task.

***EDIT***

There are recommendations of adding a boolean column that indicates if the record is to be displayed or is archived (has the meaning of "deleted" for my purposes), but this involves changing every table and every query I have done, so it won't fit for me, only as a last resort.

Comment: You could run a macro to create a table copy of each table, suffixed Audit, and use data macros to achieve this the same way triggers do in SQL Server.  A little bit of effort, but a good quick-ish fix.  A single back up table would be extremely wide column wise and would take a lot of coding.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to create a single table for records that come from every table. Is it easy to create a copy from a table using macros?

Comment: google it, copying access tables vba, then adjust accordingly

Comment: Sorry, I mean code in VBA. Edited in the Question.

Comment: A lot of this depends on the table structure.  Does every table have the same structure?  If so, you can use one function for every archive event and you can store them all in the same table if you want.  If each table has a different structure, you need a separate archive function for each table.

Comment: The tables are different, and many more can exist on the future. I am looking for a way to delete records and be able to recover them for any table structure, but seems there is nothing like that built in inside MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you have cascading deletions, as in all good designed databases? Also your INSERT in a backup table before DELETE will not solve all the issues you will face. Also copying table can result in a lot of copies that will increase your database size and you will have soon or later to clean your data.

Journaling can be better solutions?

Comment: Is journaling built in MS Access? Or, is it something I can implement for all tables at once, no matter structure?

Comment: @EduardoPoço Assuming that you and your users manage data exclusively thru Forms, you can put a call to a VBA macro in the before_update event of each form. An excellent example can be found at http://www.databasedev.co.uk/audit_trail.html. Note that it would be a good idea to add a timestamp.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I will start using forms for that purpose.